# A question about Gromov-Lawson construction

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We all know that if we consider the connected sum $S^n\# S^n$ of two spheres $S^n$ for $n\geq 3$, then by Gromov-Lawson construction(cf.  [Gromov, Mikhael; Lawson, H.Blaine Jun., The classification of simply connected manifolds of positive scalar curvature](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1971103)), we can find a metric on this space
$S^n\# S^n$ with scalar curvature $\geq c^2$ uniformly. My question is how we may make the assumption $c^2\geq 1$ by renormalizing if necessary. I got stuck in the step "renormalizing" to obtain a metric with scalar curvature $\geq 1$ uniformly. That means that I do not understand the precise meaning of the step which seems to be not difficult in an article.

Could you please give me some help with the details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would have guessed that you just multiply the metric by a positive constant and work out how that affects the scalar curvature. But then I guess you wouldn't have asked the question. Can you perhaps make clear why positive constant metric rescaling won't allow you to increase the value of $c^2$?

Comment: What's your meaning?

Comment: Sorry if my comment is not clear. If $g$ is a Riemannian metric, and $a_0>0$ is a constant, then $a_0g$ is also a Riemannian metric. I am wondering: if $g$ satisfies the condition that its scalar curvature is at least $c^2$ for some constant $c$, could you not arrange that $a_0g$ has scalar curvature at least $1$ by suitable choice of constant $a_0>0$?

Comment: @BenMcKay I would make an answer from your comment (so the question will no longer marked as "unanswered").

Answer (score 2):

When we rescale a smooth Riemannian metric $g$, i.e. we let $h=\lambda g$, where $\lambda$ is a constant, then $h$ is also a Riemannian metric just when $\lambda>0$, and then the scalar curvatures $s_g,s_h$ of $g,h$ are related by $s_h=s_g/\lambda$. A much more general result, scaling by an arbitrary positive smooth function, has a well known but more complicated [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Conformal_change) relating the scalar curvatures. In particular, if we have $s_g\ge c^2$ for some $c\ne 0$, then $s_h=s_g/\lambda \ge c^2/\lambda$, so if we pick $0<\lambda \le c^2$ we will have $s_h\ge 1$.

The paper of Gromov and Lawson is not particularly helpful for studying connected sums of spheres, since $S^n\# S^n$ is [diffeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) to $S^n$, and the metric they construct is not explicit: see the bottom of page 149, where they write

> One now observes that ... can be homotoped ...

Clearly we already know that $S^n$ has a metric of positive scalar curvature, even of positive curvature operator: the standard metric as the unit sphere in Euclidean space.